# Modify Current Value of Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays, say `multiarray`, `valsarray`, and `otherarray`. `otherarray` is a multidimensional array that supplies values to `multiarray` and `valsarray`, but besides that it is unimportant here. `valsarray` takes values from a subarray of each value in `otherarray` and `multiarray` takes straight values from `otherarray`, as demonstrated below:

```
foreach($otherarray as $other){
    foreach($other as $sub){
        $valsarray[] = $sub
    }
    $multiarray[] = array('Val1' => $other['Val1'], 'Val2' => $other['Val2']);
}
```

Now what I would like to do is append each key/value pair in `valsarray` to the current array entry of `multiarray`, to achieve a result similar to:

```
$multiarray = array('Val1' => $other['Val1'], 'Val2' => $other['Val2'], 
'VALSARRAY_KEY1' => VALSARRAY_VALUE1, ..., 'VALSARRAY_KEYN' => VALSARRAY_VALUEN)
```

I have attempted to solve this using `current` in the following fashion:

```
foreach($valsarray as $key => $val){
    current($multiarray)[$key] = $val;
}
```

But the `multiarray` remained unaltered. I may be misunderstanding how `current` works, or how to approach this problem, so any help or direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT- EXAMPLE**

```
otherarray = array(...prior array entries...,
                   array('Val1' => 'abc',
                         'Val2' => 'cde',
                         'Val3' => 'not important',
                         'Val4' => array(0 => 'subA', 1 => 'subB'),
                   ...next array entries...);

BEFORE MERGE:
multiarray = array(...prior entries...,
                   array('Val1' => 'abc',
                         'Val2' => 'cde'));
valsarray = array(0 => 'subA', 1 => 'subB');

AFTER MERGE:
multiarray = array(...prior entries...,
                   array('Val1' => 'abc',
                         'Val2' => 'cde',
                          0 => 'subA',
                          1 => 'subB'));
```

So if multiarray was a regular array instead of a multidimensional one, I would do something like:

```
foreach($valsarray as $key => $val){
    $multiarray[$key] = $val;
}
```

To achieve the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help if I have misunderstood something.

It appears that the `current()` function does not work as you assume. (Or more specifically, the internal pointer.)
If you look at the example in the PHP documentation: [`Current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php#example-5636), you will see that for `current($array)` to change elements, you need to call `next($array)` or `prev($array)`.
These function move the internal pointer of the array.

<sub>Note that in PHP 5, [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops use the internal pointer (and reset it when you start a loop), but in PHP 7, `foreach` loops do *not* use the internal pointer.</sub>

Anyway, here is my best guess at what could help you.

```
$valsarray_index = 0;
foreach ($otherarray as $other) {
    $multiarray_value = array('Val1' => $other['Val1'], 'Val2' => $other['Val2']);
    foreach ($other as $sub) {
        $multiarray_value[$valsarray_index] = $sub;
        // $multiarray_value["VALSARRAY_KEY" . $valsarray_index] = $sub;
        $valsarray[] = $sub;

        $valsarray_index += 1; // This stays in lockstep with the last index of $valsarray
    }
    $multiarray[] = $multiarray_value;
}
```

I am not exactly sure about what you want the final output to look like. If this produces incorrect information, then if would be helpful to provide some specific arrays for input and what you expect as output.

Comment: I modified my answer to include an example of what I'd like to happen. Thank you for you infomormation on `current`

Comment: Okay, still not seeing the problem, @yanman1234.  I think part of my issue is there seem to be too many `foreach` loops.  `$otherarray` does not appear to be a fully multi-dimensional array, and so sometimes the second `foreach` will be iterating over a string. (I don't think this in intended). I think it would be helpful to show either values so the main foreach loop loops at least twice, or show how my answer is incorrect (as it probably is).

Comment: Sorry, I left out the outer array on `$otherarray`, it is fixed now. Your solution actually works now that I look at it again. The `$valsarray_index` had confused me at first but I see now it is just making the new key for `$sub` to insert on. Thank you!

Comment: I could have replaced `$multiarray_value[$valsarray_index] = $sub` with `$multiarray[count($valsarray)] = $sub`, but I felt it better to just use an integer as apposed to calling a function every iteration.